# Change default Encoding in Terminator

Tags: character-encoding, gnome-terminator

The Title stays pretty much for itself.

Tried to figure it out myself but I can´t find a config-setting nor a option in the Preferences for the Encoding.

Does anybody know how to change the default Encoding in Terminator?

Comment: From the zany homepage http://software.jessies.org/terminator/ it would seem terminator is strictly UTF-8.  Which might be a wise choice.

Comment: If you're having trouble, check font. Unicode support varies a lot.

Comment: Unfortunately there are two totally different terminal emulators named Terminator: https://code.google.com/p/jessies/wiki/Terminator and https://launchpad.net/terminator. Which one do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your `.bashrc`

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_us.UTF-8
```